# Python SQLAlchemy database model for Version Control system

Tags: python, database, git, sqlalchemy

This is my first time creating a non-trivial database and I was wondering what I could do better. As the title says this will be used a in toy version control system. Most of my choices feel "random" because I do not know what is and is not important. I also can not decide on what the tables should know about themselves. For example: *Should objects belong to a commit? Is it ok to keep every object unlabeled and only have commits refer to them. And things like that.* Any review would be welcome.

```
class Object(Base):
   __tablename__ = "objects"
   oid = Column(String, primary_key= True)
   name = Column(String)
   blob = Column(BLOB)

class Commit(Base):
   __tablename__ = "commits"
   oid = Column(String, primary_key= True)
   commit_message = Column(String)
   parent_oid = Column(String, nullable= True)

   objects = relationship("Object", secondary="commit_object_association")

   repository_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("repositories.id"))
   repository = relationship("Repository", back_populates="commits")

# Many to Many 
class CommitObjectAssociation(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'commit_object_association'
   commit_oid = Column(String, ForeignKey('commits.oid'), primary_key=True)
   object_oid = Column(String, ForeignKey('objects.oid'), primary_key=True)

class Branch(Base):
   __tablename__ = "branches"
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
   name = Column(String)
   
   head_commit_oid = Column(String, ForeignKey("commits.oid"))
   
   repository_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("repositories.id"))
   repository = relationship("Repository", back_populates="branches", foreign_keys=[repository_id])

   __table_args__ = (
      UniqueConstraint('name', 'repository_id', name='unique_branch_per_repo'),
   )


class Repository(Base):
   __tablename__ = "repositories"
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement= True)
   name = Column(String)
   head_oid = Column(String, nullable= True, default= None)
   
   current_branch_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("branches.id"), nullable=True)
   current_branch = relationship("Branch", uselist=False, foreign_keys=[current_branch_id])

   creator_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable= False)
   creator = relationship("User", back_populates="repositories")

   commits = relationship("Commit", back_populates="repository")
   branches = relationship("Branch", back_populates="repository", foreign_keys="Branch.repository_id")

   __table_args__ = (
      UniqueConstraint('name', 'creator_id', name='unique_repo_per_user'),
   )

class User(Base):
   __tablename__ = "users"

   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
   name = Column(String, unique= True)
   password = Column(String)

   repositories = relationship("Repository", back_populates="creator")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## object()

```
class Object(Base):
```

This identifier does not clash with or shadow the `object()` builtin.
But still, you might give a moment's thought to giving this class
a more descriptive name, something more project-specific,
maybe `vc_object` or `vc_obj`.
I do not look forward to hallway discussions or telephone calls
where we diagnose the behavior of an `Object` which is an `object`.

Also the {oid, name, blob} columns are generic enough
that this class really needs a docstring
explaining the concept it models.
As it stands, I don't understand why we'd want to represent
this pair of rows:

- (1, "bob", "lorem ipsum")
- (2, "bob", "lorem ipsum")

That is, what does it *mean* to have distinct rows with same name?
Or perhaps we wanted a UNIQUE index there?

## singular

```
   __tablename__ = "objects"
   ...
   __tablename__ = "commits"
```

Reasonable people will disagree on this topic.
I assert it makes more sense to talk about "the commit table".
Given that it's an RDBMS table,
it is clear that we intend to store more than a single row in it.

## lint

```
   oid = Column(String, primary_key= True) ...
   parent_oid = Column(String, nullable= True)
```

Every now and again run your code through
[black *.py](https://pypi.org/project/black), please.

Or run a
[linter](https://pypi.org/project/ruff)
and heed its advice.

## plural

```
class User(Base):
   __tablename__ = "users"
```

It appears that some projects wind up adopting the
"tables are plural" rule because

1. they have a user table, and
2. sql-92 makes USER a reserved keyword, present in several commands.

Consider calling this the `vc_user` table instead.

## credentials

```
   password = Column(String)
```

That seems bad.

Do not store plaintext passwords.

Prefer to store an
[argon2id](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2)
`hash`.

## next steps

Run it, and examine some SHOW CREATE TABLE output
to verify you're happy with the defaults and with the choices
that you've made.
Pay careful attention to whether it really does make sense
for a given column to hold a NULL value.
When in doubt, add a NOT NULL constraint,
as humans can reason about queries (including JOIN queries)
on such columns more easily.

Verify that tables and indexes use a character collation
order you're happy with, typically UTF8 rather than Latin1.
Get it right from the start, so you don't have
conflicting character sets in "old" and "new" tables
which the query planner has trouble combining.

Consider using an automated tool to produce a graphical
[ERD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)#Entity_relationship_diagram_%28ERD%29_notations).

Give a little thought to how the system will evolve.
You will likely need a "test" DB environment,
which routinely gets nuked with DELETE commands
and/or DROP TABLE ... CASCADE commands.
The order in which you do things may matter,
with one DB object holding a reference on another,
thereby preventing a DROP.
You may want to script the details, for reproducibility.

Your "prod" DB environment will eventually hold
rows that you'd be sad if you lost them.
Write a brief script that dumps rows to .csv or .dump file.
Verify that it works,
for example by restoring "prod" into newly created "test" tables.

I don't know what your favorite "prod" database vendor would be,
possibly postgres.
Take advantage of the flexibility offered by the sqlalchemy connect string.
Test your code against more than one backend,
such as both postgres and sqlite.
It has its limitations, but sqlite database files
are a terrific match for rapid edit-debug cycles.
A simple `cp` command can quickly re-establish
known state from a backup DB file.

Write automated
[tests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)
that interact with your tables.